# Java Beginner Assignment

Tags: java

I am new to Java, and I am trying to make a program for the user to enter a certain number of integers and then retrieve those integers and print them back.

This works only if you input 1 integer. Otherwise, it terminates.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Number of Numbers");
        int totalNumbers = scan.nextInt();
        int[] numbers = new int[totalNumbers];
        for(int i = 0;i == (totalNumbers-1); i++){
            System.out.println("Enter the Next Number");
            numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }


        for(int i = 0;i == (totalNumbers-1); i++){
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your loop condition is your problem. It will only accept one input. The condition:

```
for(int i = 0; i == (totalNumbers-1); i++){
```

Will terminate when `i != (totalNumbers - 1)`. Your `for` loop should be read like the following:

> Initialize a new variable i to zero, then while i is equal to
>   "totalNumbers - 1", do the following block of code, then increment i
>   by 1

You probably want:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= (totalNumbers-1); i++){
```

Which can be read as:

> Initialize a new variable *i* to zero, then while *i* is LESS THAN or equal to
>   "totalNumbers - 1", do the following block of code, then increment *i*
>   by 1

Answer (score 1):

There are two bugs in your code, both are related to loop statement,

replace first loop statement by

```
for(int i = 0;i <= (totalNumbers-1); i++)
```

and replace second loop statement by

```
for(int i = 0;i <= (totalNumbers-1); i++)
```

regards.

Comment: This is same as @Kons answer

Comment: See comments in Kons answer. It helped user shaan... but user never accepted the answer. Try comment on Shaans initial question as he will get an email and might select your answer. I will upvote your answer as I know what it is like to get traction when you get started on SO

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the Number of Numbers");
    int totalNumbers = scan.nextInt();
    int[] numbers = new int[totalNumbers];
    for(int i = 0;i <= (totalNumbers-1); i++){   //changed the loop's condition
        System.out.println("Enter the Next Number");
        numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }


    for(int i = 0;i <= (totalNumbers-1); i++){  //changed the condition in the 
        System.out.println(numbers[i]);
    }

}
```

}

The reason you get to enter only 1 number is the condition you've given in the for loop.You need to enter numbers until the i<sup>th</sup> value is less than or equal to the (totalNumbers-1)
But if I were you I'd use `**for(int i = 0;i < totalNumbers1; i++)**` just sayin

Answer (score -1):

What I understood from your code is, your culprit is the following line:

```
for(int i = 0;i == (totalNumbers-1); i++){
        System.out.println("Enter the Next Number");
        numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
}
```

The loop will not execute unless and until you have `totalNumbers = 1`. Only then, you'll have `i = totalNumbers - 1 = (1 -1) = 0`, which satisfies the condition `i == (totalNumbers - 1)` inside your loop. This is the reason you can input only 1 number; if you have `totalNumbers` value other than 1, the loop will not execute and your program will terminate.

The way you wrote the for loop condition is not correct. Rather, you should write like this:

```
for(int i = 0;i <= (totalNumbers-1); i++){
     //do your work here
}
```

Write the for loop in the above way in both loops in your question.

Comment: What's the reason behind me getting downvote??? :( :( My solution seems to be ok.